# utf-8 issue when using socket in server PC

Tags: python, sockets, utf-8

I want to send some file from a client PC to a server PC using Python.
But when I run the client code, there is a problem.

Here is the client code:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((HOST,PORT))
    sock.sendall(filename.encode('utf-8'))
    print(filename.encode('utf-8'))
```

and this is the server code:

```
filename = self.request.recv(1024)
print(filename)
filename = filename.decode('utf-8')
```

When I run it within my PC (for example, server=client localhost), it runs perfectly.

But in my server PC, print result has some added text like:

```
b'filename\~~~~~~~~~~'
```

[filename result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBh7O.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQgkN.png)

So I think if the added text is gone when I use my server PC, the problem will be solved.

But I dont know how to get there.

Please let me know...

Comment: Can you show which Python version you are running, both on the client and the server machine?

Comment: I think the main problem here might be segmentation. If I'm not mistaken, you have to implement some kind of message-segmentation mechanics when you use sockets; the protocol doesn't do that for you (unlike HTTP). So it seems after the filename, the client sends more data (probably the file contents). When you call `recv(1024)`, you get the filename plus the beginning of the file content (which is a PNG file, so decoding with UTF-8 naturally fails).

Comment: I use client PC (3.6 with Pycharm) and server PC (3.5.2).

Comment: as you mentioned, I think server recevie not only filname but also data. I will check it and  matching with Python version between Server and Client

Comment: Versions 3.5 and 3.6 should be sufficiently compatible in this kind of setting, I'm pretty sure this isn't a problem here. I guess you need to find a way of signaling message boundaries.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this document](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html)? Especially the "Using a socket" section seems relevant. I don't know how much of this is taken care of by the socket server.